# Pegar array de um php após uma requisição ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tendo que fazer uma requisição ajax, que retorna mais de um valor e assim que clica nesse valor, seria executado outra requisição ajax.

Acontece que para fazer essa requisição, eu envio para o php uma requisição ajax para fazer um select, onde nesse select pode retornar um array.

**Envio a requisição e capturo o retorno**

```
 $("#txtRazaoSocial").keyup(function(){
        var dados = $("#txtRazaoSocial").val();
        if(dados.length > 2){

            var XMLHttp =  generateXMLHttp();
            XMLHttp.open("get", "classes/getData.php?dados=" + dados, true);
            XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4)
                    if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
                        var data = XMLHttp.responseText.split(/(\d+)(?=(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\sa))/);


                        if(data == ""){
                            $(".conteudo-select").html("");
                            $(".msgDados").html("Não foi encontrado nenhuma razao social");
                        }else{

                            $(".msgDados").html("");
                            $(".conteudo-select").fadeIn(500);
                            console.log(dados);
                        }


                        //var obj = {};

                    } else {
                        result.innerHTML = "Um erro ocorreu: " + XMLHttp.statusText;
                    }
            };
            XMLHttp.send(null);

        }
        else if(dados.length <= 2)
        {
            $(".conteudo-select").fadeOut(1000);
            $(".conteudo-select").html("");
            $(".msgDados").html("");

        }
```

**Pega os dados e chama o select**

```
    $dados = $_GET['dados'];
    if($dados != ''){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
            $Treinamento->getDados($dados);
        }
        else if(empty($dados)){
            $Treinamento->getDados($dados);
        }
        else{
            $Treinamento->getDados($dados);
        }
```

**Faz o select**

```
public function getDados($dados){
        try{
            $sql = "SELECT razao_social FROM prt_partner WHERE _ativo = 1 AND razao_social LIKE '%".$dados."%' ";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $key => $values){
                $this->return =  $values->razao_social;

                print_r("<a id='".str_replace(" ","",$values->razao_social)."' '>".$this->return."<br>");
            }

        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

}

O problema está que, eu como eu disse, quando eu clicar nessa no campo da div gerada, teria que fazer outro select para listar o cnpj.

Eu pensei em retornar um array do php, ai que está o problema, o responseText do generateXMLHttp, ele retorna como uma string, queria que retornasse como um array, para facilitar eu saber em qual link gerado foi clicado.

Desde já valeu galera

Comment: recomendo você fazer concatenção do lado do PHP mais ou menos assim: info##info2##info3##info4 e dar data.split('##') para tratar o array do lado javascript

Comment: valeu, ajudou muito sua resposta